# Is there a common html or xml spreadsheet format capable of storing functions for use between Excel and Google Sheets?

Tags: html, xml, excel, google-sheets

I noticed that when I exported a html spreadsheet with Google Sheets or Excel that functions were translated into literal values. Excel stores functions as Excel 2003 XML files but Google Sheets gives an error when opening such a file.

I'm looking for a human readable, html/xml file capable of storing, editing, displaying spreadsheets with functions across Excel, Google Sheets and possibly an email or webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no known solution other than converting back and forth between Excel and Google Docs.